# How can I reloaded URL link, that it stay the same after I click on submit button

Tags: javascript, php, url, page-refresh

I have simple form:

```
    <div class="form-style-2">
    <form action="" name="formular" id="formular" method="GET">
    <label for="actual_position"><span>From: <span class="required"></span></span><input name="actual_position" type="text" maxlength="512" id="actual_position" class="searchField" 
                                        <?php if(!empty($actual_position)){  ?>
                                                  value="<?php echo $_GET['actual_position']?>"
                                                <?php
                                                }else {
                                                  ?> value = ""; <?php
                                                      }  ?>/></label>

    <label for="final_position"><span>To: <span class="required"></span></span><input name="final_position" type="text" maxlength="512" id="final_position" class="searchField"     <?php if(!empty($final_position)){  ?>
                                                  value="<?php echo $_GET['final_position']?>"
                                                <?php
                                                }else {
                                                  ?> value = ""; <?php
                                                      }  ?>/></label>
<input type="submit" value="Find path" />
```

And another multiselect in form who gets values form url link and compere with database and get som results. Here is a code:

```
<table  width= "570px">  
    <tr><td width="200px" style="align:center"><b>Waypoints:</b> <br>
    <tr><td width="370px"><select style="float:center; margin-left:5px" multiple id="waypoints">

        if(!empty($urls)){
            foreach($urls as $url){
                if($result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM $table where $ID = '$url' "));
                    $atraction = $result->fetch_array();  ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo  $atraction['lat']. "," . $atraction['lon']; ?>" 
                        > <?php  echo  "<b>".$atrction['City']. ", " . $atraction['Name'];?> </option>
    <?php         
            }
        }
    ?>                                         
                      </select></td></tr>
    <br>
</table>
</form>
```

And getting ID-s from url code:

```
if(!empty($_GET[$ID])){
$urls = $_GET[$ID];
  foreach($urls as $url){ 
 //  echo $url;
  }
}
```

... and after submit, it Post to URL some variables like this:
http://127.0.0.1/responsiveweb/travel.php?actual_position=Paris&final_position=Praha&ID[]=23&ID[]=15&ID[]=55

... very important for me are ID-s values ... but when I change for example actual position and then submit I lost my ID-s and I get something like this: http://127.0.0.1/responsiveweb/travel.php?actual_position=Berlin&final_position=Praha

Can you help me how to get after clicking on submit button full url link? Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your question. What exactly do you mean by getting full URL link? Do you mean you want to know how to get the form values in PHP? Also, please include the form in your code. It makes it easier for us to understand what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I had some trouble understanding your question OP, but I think I understood somehow what you ment, so I decided to try giving you a answer.

I have re-written your code, and tried to make somehow better code-structure. I have also used form method POST in my example, so you can see how you can change the get data on the redirection url.

See my code example here: http://pastebin.com/wQ7QCBmt

I also decided to use the form method POST instead of GET, so you can easily do back-end tasks, and extend your link if neccessary. You could also add more data to the link even when using GET. You could add an hidden input inside your form, example:

`<input type="hidden" name="more_data" value="a_value" />`